# Automount separate disk

Tags: mount, fstab

I have installed system on the `/dev/sdb1`, now I want auto mount `/dev/sda1`. I tried to do it with disk name:

```
$ echo "/dev/sda1 /home/alex/olddisk ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
```

And also with UUID:

```
$ echo "UUID=2949d1df-f311-4068-b0c8-c40437738250 /home/alex/olddisk ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
```

But I don't se it in the olddisk. Moreover, after reboot I even not see grub menu and got `grub rescue>` error.

p.s I noted that disks are mounted. But problem in the grub. It shows me `grub rescure` and such device not found after reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I have had same problem, and you have to type this in the terminal:

```
        sudo amount -a
        sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and type it in manual enter this:

```
        uuid=2949d1df-f311-4068-b0c8-c40437738250              ext4      defaults    errors-noremount-ro
    1
```

and save the file, and then type this in the terminal:

```
         sudo mount -a
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: What is `amount` command? Where is mount point is /etc/fstab? This will cause fail to mount everything due to malformed fstab. Why do you post all this?

Comment: @Pilot6 should we close this answer as "potentially harmful"? Please ping back if you VTC and I'll vote along. Thanks.